# How to persist Closure in Database in Grails?

Tags: hibernate, grails, serialization, groovy

I am trying to persist a Groovy Closure (which are [allegedly serializable](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html)) as a property of one of my Grails domain objects. Currently I'm basically doing this:

```
class MyClass {
    ....
    Closure myClosure
    static mapping = { myClosure size: 1024 * 1024, type: 'blob' }
}
new MyClass(myClosure: { ... do some stuff .. }.dehydrate()).save()
```

I tried changing 'blob' to 'binary' but that doesn't work. I get an error similar to:
**context.GrailsContextLoader Error executing bootstraps: BootStrap$_obj_closure3 cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob**

How should I set up my domain object in order to be able to store a closure?

I am using Grails 2.1.1 with Groovy 2.0

Comment: try type: 'serializable' instead of type: 'blob'

Comment: I get: `Value too long for column "EXTRACT BINARY(255) NOT NULL`

Comment: And are you certain that, if you manage to store it, you will be able to retrieve and use it? Closures are translated to Java classes when compiling a Grails application.

Comment: Yes, I got it working. See my answer. For serialization, Groovy supports hydrate/dehydrate methods to take care of the context issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed this:

```
static mapping = {
    myClosure sqlType: 'blob'
}
```